# Reading multiple .csv files with varying names from URL

Tags: r, csv, url

I'm trying to read multiple .csv files from an URL starting with http. All files can be found on the same website. Generally, the structure of the file's name is: yyyy_mm_dd_location_XX.csv

Now, there are three different locations (lets say locA, locB, locC) for which there is a file for every day of the month each. So, the file name would be e.g. "2009_10_01_locA_XX.csv", "2009_10_02_locA_XX.csv" and so forth.

The structure, meaning the number of columns of all csv files is the same, however the length is not.

I'd like to combine all these files into one csv file but have problems reading them from the website due to the changing names.

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? From your question it is somewhat hard to exactly understand where the question is? Do you need a way to concatenate strings to create the file names (i.e. `paste0`). Would you rather want to harvest the web page (i.e. the `rvest`package). It is difficult to help you without further details that shows us where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi,
sorry, I try to make it more clear:
My final goal is to automatically import the data from the webpage.
I could do so by manually reading the csv files and combining them using for example:
# read first file
file_x<- read.csv("https://example-website/data/2009_10_01_locA_XX.csv", header = FALSE)
# add second file
file_y <- read.csv("https://example-website/data/2009_10_01_locA_XX.csv", header = FALSE)
files_combined <- rbind(file_x,file_y)

But this would take a rather long time, plus there will be new once every day.
I guess to answer your question: harvesting the web page

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to programmatically generate the names of the files, and then run `download.file()` to download them. Since no reproducible example was given with the question, one needs to change the code to the correct HTTP location to access the files.

```
startDate <- as.Date("2019-10-01","%Y-%m-%d")

dateVec <- date + 0:4 # create additional dates by adding integers
library(lubridate)
downloadFileNames <- unlist(lapply(dateVec,function(x) {
     locs <- c("locA","locB","locC")
     paste(year(x),month(x),day(x),locs,"XX",sep="_")
}))

head(downloadFileNames)
```

We print the `head()` of the vector to show the correct naming pattern.

```
> head(downloadFileNames)
[1] "2019_10_1_locA_XX" "2019_10_1_locB_XX" "2019_10_1_locC_XX"
[4] "2019_10_2_locA_XX" "2019_10_2_locB_XX" "2019_10_2_locC_XX"
>
```

Next, we'll create a directory to store the files, and download them.

```
# create a subdirectory to store the files
if(!dir.exists("./data")) dir.create("./data")

# download files, as https://www.example.com/2019_10_01_locA_XX.csv
# to ./data/2019_10_01_locA_XX.csv, etc. 

result <- lapply(downloadFileNames,function(x){
     download.file(paste0("https://www.example.com/",x,".csv"),
                          paste0("./data/",x,".csv"))
})
```

Once the files are downloaded, we can use `list.files()` to retrieve the path names, read the data with `read.csv()`, and combine them into a single data frame with `do.call()`.

```
theFiles <- list.files("./data",pattern = ".csv",full.names = TRUE)
dataList <- lapply(theFiles,read.csv)
data <- do.call(rbind,dataList)
```